# Диагональный слайдер контента

Tags: jquery, адаптивная-верстка, html, вёрстка, css

Приветствую, знатоки.

Пришла ко мне задача запилить вот такой слайдер:
[image]

На удивление, гугл ничем мне не помог, поэтому прошу помощи у вас.
Может кто встречался с аналогичной задачей или может подсказать в каком направлении мне продолжить поиск?

Comment: попросите дизов отрисовать вам SVG маску одного слайда, и делайте ей background-image

Comment: @fenris, если хотите, то я [могу показать "полупример"][1]. Все расчеты в нём сделаны вручную и приблизительно. Организовать это можно и в виде плагина, ничего особо сложного там нет, а особенно, если все изображения будут одного размера. 

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/3bwbo0ab/

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо большое, но видимо я не правильно описал что мне нужно.
смена слайдов должна происходить как [здесь][1]

  [1]: http://pavelvolya.com/

Comment: @fenris, плагин такой, вы вряд ли найдёте. Поэтому есть несколько путей решений:

1. Пишите сами с нуля, если хватает знаний.
2. Нанимаете профессионала.
3. Берёте за основу какой-нибудь похожий плагин с параллакс эффектом и допиливаете до нужной кондиции.
4. Самый простой, но не кошерный вариант - скомуниздить скрипты с того сайта.

Comment: Ну и, стандартно:
@fenris, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот, я сделал очень хитрую конструкцию: http://jsfiddle.net/6b9gjagL/3/

HTML:

```
<div class='skew'>
    <div style="background: url(http://placekitten.com/400/600);" class='bg'>1st</div>
</div>
<div class='skew'>
    <div style="background: url(http://placekitten.com/401/600);" class='bg'>2nd</div>
</div>
...
```

Весь необходимый контент должен лежать в .bg как обычно.

CSS:

```
.skew {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg);
    transform: skewY(-10deg);
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}
.bg {
    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
    transform: skewY(10deg);
    padding-top: 35px;
}
```

.skew наклонен на -10 градусов. А внутри него находится .bg, наклоненный на 10. Так .bg оказывается не наклонен, зато белая граница — наклонена. Чтобы избежать белых полей .bg больше .skew.

JS:

```
$(document).on('ready scroll', function (e) {
    $('.bg').each(function (num) {
        $(this).css('margin-top', (-(num * 405) + $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
    });
});
```

Все просто: мы поднимаем все .bg так, чтобы их начала были на уровне верха страницы. Если высота окна будет больше высоты .bg, получится белое пятно, так что высоты элементов тоже стоит контролировать из JS. Обратите внимание на -(num * 405). Если .skew будут разного размера, нужно просуммировать высоту всего,что находится до текущего .bg

Кстати, решение работает даже если трансформации не поддерживаются. Граница просто перестанет быть наклонной.

Comment: Возможно ли сделать слайдер с одним диагональным углом? Чтобы слева был меняющийся слайдер, а справа статичная картинка?
Вот на этом сайте: http://koleso.96.lt/
Уже не знаю как это реализовать, помогите пожалуйста!